# React PerfectScrollbar causes my react web crashes

Tags: reactjs

This is my code snippet, pls help

```
<div >
                    {allMemberList !== null && !loadingAllMemberList && (
                    <>
                    
                            {allMemberList.data.map(item =>(
                                <PerfectScrollbar className="card-body dz-scroll" >
                                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                        
                                        <li class="list-group-item p-3 py-2"> <img className='img-responsive '
                                        src= {item.user.photo_url} alt=""/> 
                                        
                                            <span  className='text-center ml-3'> {item.user.display_name} </span>
                                            <span className='font-weight-light'>{item.user.username} </span>
                        
                                        </li>
                                        
                                    </ul>
                                </PerfectScrollbar>
                            ))}
                    </>
                    
                    )}
```

Error message=> Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: codesandbox link?

Comment: sry i didnt do it on codesandbox

Comment: would be hard to debug the issue.